# how to populate dynamic drop drown list for city and state using php?

Tags: php

I am using this code to populate the dropdowns for city and state from the database. But now i want to have a dynamic dropdown where I select the state and according to the state the cities present in that state will populate.  Need your help in how to do this .Thanks in advance.

```
     $query3 = "SELECT state FROM states";
     $result3 = mysqli_query($db,$query3);


     $query4 = "SELECT city FROM cities";
     $result4 = mysqli_query($db,$query4);


     if (!$result3) { 
     echo("Error, the query could not be executed: " .
     mysqli_error($db) . "</p>");
     mysqli_close($db);
     }

if (!$result4) { 
     echo("Error, the query could not be executed: " .
     mysqli_error($db) . "</p>");
     mysqli_close($db);
     }


<select style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;" id="state" name="state"  >
                <option></option>
                <?php
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
     echo '<option value="' . $row['state'] . '">' . $row['state']. '</option>';
       }
       ?>
                </select>


<select style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;" id="city" name="city"  >
              <option></option>
                <?php
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)){
     echo '<option value="' . $row['city'] . '">' . $row['city']. '</option>';
       }
       ?>
                </select>
```

Comment: You have to post your database structure to...

Comment: But do you have a state_id in the cities table, right?

Comment: i have the state name present besides the city name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have you to use AJAX.

1st Drop down box (states). onchange you need to trigger an ajax call to get cities under that state.

example:

```
<?php
$query3 = "SELECT state FROM states";
$result3 = mysqli_query($db,$query3);
?>
    <select id="statesSelectBox" name="state" onchange="getStates();">
  <?php
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
         echo '<option value="' . $row['state'] . '">' . $row['state']. '</option>';
  }?>
    </select>

    <div id="updateCities">

    </div>

    <script>
        function getStates(){
             $.ajax({
                 url:'mydomain.com/getCities.php',
                 cache:false,
                 data:{state:$('#statesSelectBox').val()},
                 beforeSend:function(){
                    // do something here. possibly a loader
                 },
                 success:function(response){
                    // remove the loader here
                    $('#updateCities').html(response);
                 }
             })
        }
    </script>
```

In getCities.php you should have

```
<?php
$query4 = "SELECT city FROM cities WHERE your_state_id = ".$_POST['state'];
$result4 = mysqli_query($db,$query4);
?>
<select>
   <option>-- Select City --</option>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)){ 
       echo '<option value="' . $row['city'] . '">' . $row['city']. '</option>';
 } ?>
</select>
```

I just wrote this quickly without testing it. This should help you get an idea as to how you can take the approach.

Comment: after selecting a state the cities are not getting populated for that particular state

Comment: I just updated the code a bit. You should pass $query4 = "SELECT city FROM cities WHERE your_state_id = ".$_POST['state']; State id or shortcode as you prefer. That would do the filter.

Comment: i am getting the response in the browser but it is not getting reflected on the page

Comment: You need to update the div using that div dom id. In ajax success function you can do $('#divID').html(response);